# Chip on engineered wood floor

Tags: flooring

I got engineered wood installed last week in my house.  I noticed there is about a 3mm circular chip.  Is there anything I can do to prevent it from further chipping ?  Its glued down on concrete.  The wear on the weed is 2mm, so I am not sure if I am seeing the ply or the inner wear.  Its not deep.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not likely to delaminate further, but you could color it with stain or marker and lay in some clear epoxy or urethane varnish to seal it up. You could press in some grain texture when the material is semi-hard.